# remove unnamed colums pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm a student and have a problem that i cant figure it out how to solve it.i have csv data like this :

```
"","","","","","","","","",""
"","report","","","","","","","",""
"","bla1","bla2","","","","bla3","","",""
"","bla4","bla5","","","","","bla6","",""
"","bla6","bla7","bla8","","1","2","3","4","5"
"","bla9","bla10","bla11","","6","7","8","9","10"
"","bla12","bla13","bla14","","11","12","13","14","15"
"","","","","","","","","",""
```

code for reading csv like this :

```
SMT = pd.read_csv(file.csv, usecols=(5,6,7,8), skiprows=(1,2,3), nrows=(3))
SMT.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

SMT print out :

```
  Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6 Unnamed: 7 Unnamed: 8
0          1          2          3          4
1          6          7          8          9
2         11         12         13         14
```

expected output :

```
 1          2          3          4
 6          7          8          9
11         12         13         14
```

i already trying `skiprows=(0,1,2,3)` but it will be like this :

```
           1          2          3          4
0          6          7          8          9
1         11         12         13         14
2          0          0          0          0
```

i already trying to put `index=Flase` `SMT = pd.read_csv(file.csv,index=False, usecols=(5,6,7,8), skiprows=(1,2,3), nrows=(3))` or `index_col=0`/`None`/`False`is not working, and the last time I tried it like this :

```
df1 = SMT.loc[:, ~SMT.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```

and i got

`Empty DataFrame
columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2]`

i just want to get rid the Unnamed: 5 ~ Unnamed: 8, how the correct way to get rid of this Unnamed thing ?

Comment: when there's no column name then pandas defaults to using unnamed, so instead of removing it, just rename your columns `SMT.columns = [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: yeah that's it, why I did not think about it, silly me, thanks a lot @Yuca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "unnamed" just says, that pandas does not know how to name the columns. So these are just names. You could set the names like this in the `read_csv`

```
pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols=(5,6,7,8), skiprows=3, nrows=3, header=0, names=["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"])
```

Output:

```
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0   1   2   3   4
1   6   7   8   9
2  11  12  13  14
```

You have to set `header=0` so that pandas knows that this is usually the header. Or you set `skiprows=4`

Comment: @HazelR nice to hear. If that solved your problem please consider upvoting the answer and mark it as solution.

Comment: i already upvote it several times but it says it wont display it cause my rep is under 15
this the massage
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

Just assign new column names:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', usecols=[5,6,7,8], skiprows=[1,2,3], nrows=3)
 df.columns = range(1, 1+len(df.columns))
```

Comment: thaks a lot for the help sir @ASGM